# Joomla 2.5 hide div

Tags: php, css, html, joomla2.5

I'm trying to hide a div in my template if the URL that is opened is't the base URL or the home page. Now when a user opens a link a div should be invisible. Can I detect and do this in Joomla 2.5 with php and how can I do this?

Comment: Why not just create a custom module,then configure it to display in any page you want.

Comment: @Lake this is a module,but the problem is it cannot be hidden at this URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by using javascript:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("base url")>0){
    $('something').show();
}
else{
        $('something').hide();
}
```

demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/ZHsH7/

Comment: The div is called id="icetabs" that means at'something' goes icetabs?Sorry for dumb question:)

Comment: I've followed your advice and here is what I did 
if(window.location.href.indexOf("http://www.mysite.com/")>0){
    $('#icetabs').show();
}
else{
        $('#icetabs').hide();

Is this ok?

Comment: You have to add jquery for this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: now it always sets the div hidden,whatever the link is www.myweb.com or www.myweb.com/categories.html. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
if(JRequest::getVar('view') == "frontpage" && JRequest::getVar('option') == 'com_content) {
    //You are viewing the homepage!
}
```

Note: This will not break even if you have a component installed called `frontpage`

An alternative

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    echo 'This is the front page';
}
```

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page